# Producer timeout while sending requests on ActiveMQ Artemis broker

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to introduce a timeout on my producer when sending messages to ActiveMQ Artemis broker 2.17.0. I use the following code for this purpose

```java
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactoryOnline() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl,username,password);
    connectionFactory.setCallTimeout(5000);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsPoolConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory() {
    JmsPoolConnectionFactory poolingFactory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
    poolingFactory.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactoryOnline());
    poolingFactory.setMaxConnections(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
    poolingFactory.setMaxSessionsPerConnection(MAX_SESSIONS_PER_CONNECTION);
    poolingFactory.setConnectionIdleTimeout(0);

    return poolingFactory;
}
```

When I simulate losing network on the ActiveMQ Artemis node using `iptables -A INPUT -s ip_producer -j DROP` I can see on producer side that current connections honor the timeout of 5sec initially set.

Unfortunately following requests (new connections) seem to ignore it since I can observe producer waiting for the next calls up to Connection timeout interval (60sec) before declaring the request broken.

Can you guide me how to resolve this, or point to me what am I doing wrong and I cannot set a timeout on my producer?

Comment: Do you have any thread dumps which demonstrate where the new connections are waiting for 60 seconds? This sounds like a possible bug or it could be that the code is in an area where the call timeout doesn't apply.

Comment: Actually, I would like to clarify if callTimeout is about also acquiring connections because first time it fails ```Timed out after waiting 5,000 ms for response when sending packet 45 [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]``` and then I suppose it has no longer a connection with the broker (or the broker closes it). Then the second time it is called as I can now understand it tries to acquire a new one and it fails after it expires the connection timeout set and not immediately after 5sec as I had set on ConnectionFactory callTimeout (still no network available). Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: This is also what I was attempting to clarify which is why I asked for the thread dump. I wanted to see exactly where the code was waiting so I could look at the code and determine if the call timeout applies there. Without such detail it will be hard to answer your question conclusively.

Comment: Also, the broker won't close the connection because the client timed out its call. The broker doesn't know or care about such client timeouts. However, *Spring* might close the connection itself upon receiving the Exception generated by the timeout.

Comment: Justin thanks for the response, I'll try to extract some logs hopefully soon and I hope they shall be helpful

Comment: Ok in the following link https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wb1k12yoarotbz/example.log?dl=0​​​​​​​ you can find the part of logs that should be of interest

Comment: Unfortunately that's just a log file and not a thread dump so it doesn't really help. I need a thread dump to see what the threads are doing during the 60-second wait.

Answer (score 0):

The `ConnectionTTL` attribute of `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` determines how long a connection will be keep alive in the absence of any data arriving and its default value is 60 seconds.

Seting the `ConnectionTTL` attribute with a value lower than 60000 will reduce the connection timeout.

Comment: Thanks Domenico, if I understand correctly callTimeout is triggered after the connection is initiated correct? Therefore the only way to set a timeout on producer will be by using the connectionTTL which though has the trade-off of opening/closing connections frequently (expensive operation). Is there a workaround on this ? Losing network is rare, so I would not like to change ConnectionTimeout permanently for such a rare case